# Simple HTML Dom Parser: How to insert to elements

Tags: html-parsing, simple-html-dom

I am trying to insert (append) into an element ... "body" specifically.

I am able to do this this way at the moment:

```
$var = "some JS stuff";
$e = $htmlDOM->find("body", 0);
$e->outertext = '<body>' . $e->innertext . $var . '</body>';
```

My issue is that this fixes `<body>` but the actual html might have js or id etc attached to `<body>` and I will like to maintain that if it is the case.

The docs don't seem to show a method for this.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After looking at the source code, I found that the way to go about it is to use

```
$var = "some JS stuff";
$e = $htmlDOM->find("body", 0);
$e->outertext = $e->makeup() . $e->innertext . $var . '</body>';
```

That is, the undocumented `makeup()` function will build the tag and any associated text/code.