# Simple HTML DOM How to add tag and choose 2 classes?

Tags: php, html

*I have a code:*

```
$data = PhpSimple\HtmlDomParser::str_get_html($result);
foreach($data->find($this->owner->selector) as $img) {
    $dataSrc = 'data-src';
    $img->$dataSrc = $img->src;
    $img->src = $loading;
}
```

Where I add to all tags img attributes. I need after each tag  insert a tag noscript. Tell me how to do it?

```
<noscript>
  <img src='mySource' />
</noscript>
```

And the second question is how to specify the selector 2 class, as in the CSS, 
reality turned out to specify only one class:

```
find('div[class=l-column_3] img')
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12252843/simple-html-dom-parser-how-to-insert-to-elements), where he finds the following workaround (edited it for your requirement):

```
$var = "<noscript><img src="mySource" /></noscript>";
$img->outertext = $img->makeup() . $img->innertext . $var;
```

---

Or you can use,

```
$img->outertext = $img->outertext;
```

---

In that case, have you tried this?

```
$data->find('div.l-column.l-column_3 img')
```

Comment: Unfortunately, 1 answer - I get: 
Call to undefined method simplehtmldom_1_5\simple_html_dom_node::append()
2) answer I need 2 class in 1 selector like a find('div.l-column.l-column_3')

Comment: Edited the answer, hopefully that will work for you :)